How can we use poetry virtual environments with Neovim?
I am trying to find the equivivalent of Ctrl + p then selecting the Python interpreter from the specified path of venv in VS code. How is it done in Neovim? (Lazyvim to be precise).
I didn't find any resources to do it.
